# Django Link only opens in new Tab, no JavaScript in use

Tags: python, html, django

The links in the Django project I created are not opened when clicked, but only if I open them in a new tab. I found an answer for this problem, that this could be a problem with javaScript, but I have no javaScript in use and I don't know what to do.

This is how I enabled the link in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'example' param1 param2 %}" target="_self"><button>Edit</button></a>
```

I have used the target attribute of the HTML tag with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using a button instead of a link.
Try changing to:

```
<a href="{% url 'example' param1 param2 %}" target="_self"> Edit </a>
```